# How to open a modal using Kendo UI grid that has a list inside it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo UI in my asp.net mvc project.

I have an issue for displaying modal. In my grid, I want to add an extra column that has a button in it.

When the user clicks that button, I need to show a list from another table that has the ID of the current table, and show it in modal.

I would really appreciate if you could help me.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClinicManagement.Models.Reagent>().Name("PersonGrid")
                            .Name("PersonGrid")
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(90);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.Family).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(90);
                                columns.Bound(p => p.CardNumber).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains))).Width(90);
                                columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails")).Width(150);
                            })
                           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                               .Ajax()
                               .PageSize(20)
                               .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                               .Sort(sort => sort.Add(p => p.Name).Ascending())
                               .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                               .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "Reagents"))
                               .Read(read => read.Action("ReadReagent", "Reagents"))
                               .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Reagents"))
                               .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Reagents"))
                  ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your code looks similar to the demo [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custom-command). You just need to finish it up:

First, create a modal on the page:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Customer Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(300)       
)
```

The sample uses a kendo template to display the details, so you could add a kendo list in there (you would need to use `.ToHtmlString()` since it is a [nested control](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-to-use-kendo-ui-widgets-inside-grid-client-column-templates)). I prefer a different approach where I can use a partial view with a view model:

Create a view model with the list items and other properties to display:

```
public class DetailsViewModel
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ... etc
    public List<string> MyListItems;
}
```

Create a partial view for the details with a list (or grid) on it:

```
@model DetailsViewModel
<div>
... // Show fields, etc.
@(Html.Kendo().ListBox()
    ... other list options
    .BindTo(Model.MyListItems)
    .Deferred()   // Need for nested control
</div>
```

Create a controller action to return the partial:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDetailsView(int personId)
{
    // fetch data
    // Fill the viewmodel 
    var vm = new DetailsViewModel
    {
        PersonId = data.PersonId,
        Name = data.Name,
        MyListItems = context.Items.Where(i => i.PersonId == personId).ToList()
    }
    return PartialView("_Details", vm);
}
```

The javascript code for the button click will open the window and tell it to load the partial view from controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDetails(personId) {
        var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
        wnd.refresh({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetailsView","Person", new { personId = "__personid__" })'
                        .replace("__personid__", personId )
                });
        wnd.open();
    }
</script>
```

Finally, change the custom command to pass in the Id:

```
.Click("showDetails(PersonId)")
```

EDIT - or use a template for your button:

```
columns.Template(t => { }).Width(150)
       .ClientTemplate(@"<a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onclick="showDetails(PersonId)">Details</a>");
```

Comment: thank you so much for your complete answer. but i have an issue in the .click part in custom command. when I put that -- (#= PersonId #) -- I won't see my List but when i erase it i can see my List.

Comment: @farshidtorkaman You could try just `(PersonId)` or see my edit for using a template column instead.